# RoleManager.FindByNameAsync throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In my `Startup.cs` file, in the `Configure`-method I'm trying to seed some roles.
I'm injecting the `IServiceScopeFactory` in the method call:

```
RoleSeeder(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>());
```

in this method I create an new object (of course with the service scope factory set) and call the `Seed` method on it:

```
public void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{            
    using(var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        CreateRoleIfNotExists("Finance");
        CreateRoleIfNotExists("Admin");
    }
}
```

The `CreateRoleIfNotExists` method:

```
private async void CreateRoleIfNotExists(string role)
{
    var roles = roleManager.Roles;
    if (await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role) == null)
    {
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole { Name = role });
    }
}
```

The `FindByNameAsync` method throws the exception, although the  `FindByNameAsync` is declared as an instance variable. The same exception raises when calling `RoleExistsAsync`.

What am I missing?

Comment: a little defensive code would go a long way. Also explicit dependency principle should be observed, and finally DO NOT use `async void` except for exception handlers, use `async Task`

Answer (score 0):

Scope also we need read from ServiceProvider.Below code is working fine for us.

```
using (var scope = builder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
{
    var _userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>();
    var hrRole = new ApplicationRole() { Name = StandardRoles.HumanResource, ClientId = null, IsActive = true, CreatedWhen = DateTime.UtcNow, ShortName = StandardRoles.HumanResource.ToLower(), RoleGuid = Guid.NewGuid(), Description = "HumanResource" };

    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(hrRole);
}
```

It may helps you.